# Cannot enter admin section in opencart nginx

Tags: nginx, opencart

I have transferred by Opencart websites from Apache to Nginx.In Apache everything was working fine,in Nginx I am unable to enter the admin section despite the correct password and keeps on showing the login page with every subsequent attempt.Besides that the addtocart button doesn't react.The config file seems ok.I have tried different options nothing has help so far.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
   server {
          listen 80;
          server_name opencart.local;
  return 301 $scheme://www.opencart.local$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 80; # listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
server_name www.opencart.local;
root /home/arch/mysites/opencart;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
charset UTF-8;
#autoindex off;

access_log /var/log/nginx/opencart.local.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/opencart.local.error.log;
# Add trailing slash to */admin requests.
rewrite /admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

 location /image/data {
    autoindex on;
  }
location /admin {
    index index.php;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri @opencart;
}
location @opencart {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx 
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}


}
```

Comment: i don't much about nginx config but can this `lo cation /admin` unnecessary space in word location be cause of this problem ?

Comment: I did a fresh install of an Opencart shop an it works on Nginx with the above configuration.The admin section and addtocart buttons are working.Really beats me.:-(

Comment: location /admin corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.Actually there are several vhosts named as opencart.local in my /etc/hosts file as under.

```
 127.0.0.1 opencart.local opencart
 127.0.0.1 opencart1.local opencart1
```

In my config file I removed the first server section:

```
 server {
      listen 80;
      server_name opencart.local;
 return 301 $scheme://www.opencart.local$request_uri;
}
```

In the next section I wrote:

```
   server {
   listen 80; # listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
   server_name  opencart.local www.opencart.local;  <---
   root /home/arch/mysites/opencart;
    index index.php index.html
```

It was probably the result of how host names where specified in /etc/hosts file.Now I can enter the admin section and the addtocart button also works.